# HP ML350e Gen8 - RAID card "exceeded option ROM space" - can't disable anything

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I've got an ML350eG8 and tried to add a P410 RAID controller. When I add the card it will try to start up and throws a "exceeded option ROM space" type error. I can get into the RBSU but if I disable the PXE boot and exit, it doesn't save the changes. If I try to disable the internal network card or internal RAID card, it doesn't even update the setting on screen in RBSU.

I think the too many ROMs issue breaks the RBSU. Amongst other things. Which is pretty useless.

I can take the P410 out and set the options (disable PXE, disable RAID, disable onboard network) and that's all fine. Then I put the P410 back in and it puts everything back to "default" values.

If I try to run the setup util for the internal B210i controller, it runs the "intelligent provisioning" thing which gets about 1/3rd of the way through booting and crashes. I don't actually want to use it as a RAID card, just SATA mode, but it resets to RAID mode and if I turn it back to SATA mode, it doesn;t save the changes.

Is there a way I can disable network/internal RAID with hardware switches?? The software seems to be designed to break itself. Or any other option ROMs I can disable somehow?? (Other than using an axe on the stupid thing...)